# Woocommerce how to use hook on_new_order and start function when order status processing?

Tags: php, woocommerce

add_action('woocommerce_new_order', 'call_order_to_tsm', 2 );

function call_order_to_tsm($order_id)
{
$order = new WC_Order($order_id);

```
$first_name = $order->get_billing_first_name();
$last_name = $order->get_billing_last_name();
$phone = $order->get_billing_phone();
$email = $order->get_billing_email();
$city = $order->get_billing_city();
$address = $order->get_billing_address_1();
$price = $order->get_total();
$items = $order->get_items();
$status = $order->get_status();

$payment_date = $order->get_date_paid();
$temp2 = date_create($payment_date);
$datePayment = date_format($temp2, "Y/m/d H:i:s");

$order_date = $order->get_date_created();;
$temp = date_create($order_date);
$date = date_format($temp, "Y/m/d H:i:s");

$products = [];

foreach ($items as $index => $item) {
    $product = [];
    $product_name = $item->get_name();
    $product_quantity = $item->get_quantity();
    $product['produktas'] = $product_name;
    $product['kiekis'] = $product_quantity;
    $products[] = $product;
}

$json = json_encode($products, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

$message =
    'Užsakymo data: ' . $date . "\n" .
    'Vardas: ' . $first_name . "\n" .
    'Pavardė: ' . $last_name . "\n" .
    'Miestas: ' . $city . "\n" .
    'Adresas: ' . $address . "\n" .
    'Prekės: ' . $json ."\n" .
    'Kaina: ' . $price . "\n" .
    'Apmokejimo data: ' . $datePayment . "\n" .
    'Statusas: ' . $status;

$TotalOrders = [
    'email' => $email,
    'phone' => $phone,
    'objectname' => 'web_testas',
    'msg' => $message
];

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'www.url.com',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $TotalOrders,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH: XMLHttpRequest'
    ),
));

curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

}

I Am trying to send every new order after payment to other system.

How to combine new_order hook and order_processing? Prevent pending or canceled orders

Comment: Just wonder why can't you use the default woocomemrce web hook to shoot out order, Do you really need a function for this ?

Comment: i am using default woocommerce hook